# Are .htaccess redirects secure/reliable (website maintenance)?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rewrite, maintenance

Our website will be going down for around an hour or so for maintenance. All users need to be redirected to a page indicating that the website is receiving an update and/or under maintenance.

Will using the following `.htaccess` rules reliably prevent all users access from the website and reliably redirect all traffic that doesn't match my IP to the maintenance page? i.e. there is no way for anyone to bypass these redirect/rewrite rules?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.192\.192\.192$
RewriteRule $ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it depends on how much of your site/server you are taking down and whether you have other/conflicting `.htaccess` files elsewhere on your filesystem? But otherwise, if `.htaccess` and mod_rewrite is still available then your temporary redirect should work OK. There is no way for a *user* to bypass those rules unless they somehow hack your server.

Bear in mind that mod_rewrite directives in parent directories can be completely overridden by child directives, further down the filesystem path. For example, if you have a directory `/foo` with its own `.htaccess` file that uses mod_rewrite (ie. `/foo/.htaccess`) then should someone request `/foo/bar` your parent mod_rewrite directives will be overridden and the redirect will not occur. For this reason, these directives would be better in the server config - in a *vhost* or *server* context - so they cannot be overridden. Or use mod_authz_core/host and customise the response.

However, if this is an existing site that is already indexed by search engines then you should consider sending a 503 Service Unavailable response together with a `Retry-After` HTTP response header (indicating the hour of maintenance) - instead of a redirect. This is the preferred response in order to preserve SEO.

See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55659/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack for more on the 503 response:

- [Website is under maintenance - how to restrict access?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/website-is-under-maintenance-how-to-restrict-access)